# Constructor arguments in autowiring sources

Tags: java, spring, autowired

What exactly causes this?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: \
No unique bean of type [fi.utu.keycard.business.KeyCardManager] \
is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: \
[dataBaseTarget, database]

// etc. (rest of Stack Trace is irrelevant)
```

What I need is autowiring 3 things: validator, ldap connection and database connection.

I call it:

```
@Controller
Controller(KeyCardManager database,
           LdapPersonDao personManager,
           GiveFormValidator validator)
```

The error seems to cause by another bean, if I change the order of these parameters. I have no signing-in, so I dont have UserDetails or so.

Answer (score 3):

The fix is probably something like this:

```
public Controller(
    @Qualifier("beanQualifier") KeyCardManager database,
    LdapPersonDao personManager,
    GiveFormValidator validator
)
```

Since there are apparently two beans of type `KeyCardManager` in your application context, you need to tell the context which one to wire.

Unfortunately the `@Qualifier` mechanism doesn't work with bean names, you must either annotate the actual bean with a corresponding `@Qualifier` or add a `<qualifier>` element to the XML bean definition.

The `@Resource` annotation works with bean names, but it doesn't support Constructor parameters (that's not Spring's fault, it's a [JSR-250](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=250) standard annotation with `@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD})`)

**Reference:**

- [Autowiring Collaborators](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire)
- [Fine-tuning annotation-based
  autowiring with qualifiers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

---

### Troubleshooting

If you don't know why there are two beans of the same type in the context, first of all navigate to the bean interface (I assume `KeyCardManager` is an interface, if not, do the same thing for the class anyway) and if you use Eclipse select `Navigate > Open Type Hierarchy`. If you find more than one concrete class that inherits from `KeyCardManager` (including `KeyCardManager` itself), then there's probably your problem.

If that is not the case, you probably have two beans of the same type in your application context. One way that can happen is when you define a bean through both XML and [classpath scanning](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning). I.e. if you have this line in your XML:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

Make sure you don't manually wire any beans from the `org.example` package (or you will have double beans, which can lead to the problem you have).

Answer (score 1):

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [fi.utu.keycard.business.KeyCardManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [dataBaseTarget, database]

It seems you are autowiring by class type. but there are multiple bean available in the context with same class. which are `dataBase` & `dataBaseTarget`

**byType**

> Allows a property to be autowired if
>   there is exactly one bean of the
>   property type in the container. If
>   there is more than one, a fatal
>   exception is thrown, and this
>   indicates that you may not use byType
>   autowiring for that bean. If there are
>   no matching beans, nothing happens;
>   the property is not set. If this is
>   not desirable, setting the
>   dependency-check="objects" attribute
>   value specifies that an error should
>   be thrown in this case.

- [Document](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html)

Comment: I found the problem. My validator must use database and ldap connections too, so I had first autowired the validator and then database and ldap in its constructor. It is double autowiring indeed! But now my problem is how can I get the database and ldap work in validator? With no wiring, they return null. Any help?